# Every derived table must have its own alias. using mysql and netbeans

Tags: mysql

I want to get sum of TotAmount from unique SONumbers. So I used this code. But it gives me the error:

> Every derived table must have its own alias

Please help me to solve this.

My code:

```
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery ("SELECT TotAmount 
                               From (SELECT Distinct SONumber From sale) 
                               where DateTime between '" + FromDate + " 
00:00:00" + "' AND '" + ToDate  + " 00:00:00" + "' ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Every derived table (subquery) should have an alias, which you can give using `AS`:

```
... From (SELECT Distinct SONumber From sale) where ...
```

Provide an alias for the subquery

```
... From (SELECT Distinct SONumber From sale) AS some_alias where ...
```

Comment: Note that the `AS` is optional

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add an alias to your subquery like:

```
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery ("SELECT sum(TotAmount) 
                               From (SELECT Distinct TotAmount,DateTime,SONumber From sale) t
                               where DateTime between '" + FromDate + " 
                                00:00:00" + "' AND '" + ToDate  + " 00:00:00");
```

Here, `(SELECT Distinct SONumber From sale)` is now your sub-table named `t`. Note that `t` is an `alias` here.

However, this also will not work because there is no `TotAmount` and `Datetime` columns returning from your sub-table. You need to add those columns as well, or use a `join` and connect to the table where those columns are existing.

Comment: Thank you very mush. but there is no tables to get values. I want get values from one table. Those TotAmount and SONumber is located in same table. I need to get sum of TotAmount for unique SONumbers.

Comment: Then you need to add those columns in your subtable and use "sum" keyword. Updated my answer.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that using my table. Table Name = sale , Columns TotAmount and SONumber.  DateTime is not a problem. I Need Sum of TotAmount of Distinct SONumber FROM sale table